# How to publish api specific mediation policy with rest

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

If I create or update a policy using the `rest api`.

```
POST /api/am/publisher/v0.12/apis/{apiId}/policies/mediation
```

Or

```
PUT api/am/publisher/v0.12/apis/{apiId}/policies/mediation/{mediationPolicyId}
```

The changes does not apply until I publish the api again from the UI.
I can live with it working like that the first time but I want to be able to change the policy without using the UI.

I have tried `publish` the `api` with the following call

```
POST /apis/change-lifecycle?apiId={apiId}&action=Publish
```

But it does not help.

As a side note, I can update the api definition without publishing the api so I think I'm just missing something about how the mediation policies works.

Any one that got this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a sequence to an API is a 2 step task.

1) Add 1 or more sequences to an API.

2) Apply one of them to the API.

You have done 1. For the second, you need to update the API with a proper `sequences`property like this.

```
"sequences": [{"name":"json_validator","type": "in"},{"name":"log_out_message","type": "out"}]
```

You can find a sample here.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM2xx/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIIndividual#apisApiIdPut

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine. I think the easiest thing for me was to fetch the api and then modify the sequence property to create the update request.